# How to access WCF RIA service from Windows Service?

Tags: c#, soap, wcf-ria-services

I have a functioning Silverlight 4 application (VS2010, SL4, WCF RIA, hosted on my dev box using Cassini, 64-bit Windows 7).  Inside the ClientBin directory I have an .svc file that describes my service:

```
<% @ServiceHost Service="MyApp.Services.MyService 
Factory="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHostFactory" %>
```

When I browse to http://localhost:52878/ClientBin/MyApp-Services-MyService.svc I see the following:

> You have created a service. To test
>   this service, you will need to create
>   a client and use it to call the
>   service. You can do this using the
>   svcutil.exe tool from the command line
>   with the following syntax:
>       svcutil.exe http://localhost:52878/ClientBin/MyApp-Services-MyService.svc?wsdl

I want to access that service from a Windows Service application. My understanding is that I need to enable SOAP end-points in order to make this happen. So, I add the following to my web.config file:

```
<domainServices>
  <endpoints>
    <add name="soap" 
        type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.SoapXmlEndpointFactory, 
        System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, 
        Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </endpoints>
</domainServices>
```

Firstly, Intellisense complains about the presence of the  tag, saying:

> The element system.ServiceModel has
>   invalid child element domainServices.

Secondly, the aforementioned Silverlight application stops working, presumably because this change breaks the underlying web services.

Thirdly, it appears that the System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting assembly doesn't actually contain the SoapXmlEndpointFactory type; if I try to browse to the service after adding the above to web.config I see:

> Could not load type
>   'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.SoapXmlEndpointFactory'
>   from assembly
>   'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

If I inspect the assembly using Reflector, I see that it contains the DomainServiceEndpointFactory and PoxBinaryEndpointFactory types, but no SoapXmlEndpointFactory.

Could someone please let me know how I should be doing this?  I can't believe that it should be this hard to simply consume a WCF RIA service in something other than a Silverlight application!

Comment: Some suggestions from the SL forum (http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/180880/409333.aspx) include setting Copy Local to true on the System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting assembly (doesn't work as the problem is that the specified type is missing from that assembly) and ensuring that the .NET Framework 4.0 is installed (it is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried just executing

> svcutil.exe
>   http://localhost:52878/ClientBin/MyApp-Services-MyService.svc?wsdl

Alternatively, have you installed the RIA Services toolkit?
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7b43bab5-a8ff-40ed-9c84-11abb9cda559&displaylang=en

It's required for SOAP and JSON endpoints

Comment: I installed the RIA Services Toolkit (from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7b43bab5-a8ff-40ed-9c84-11abb9cda559&displaylang=en), changed the domainServices declaration to use the correct namespace and assembly, and it now works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of ...

> System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting

use the assembly ...

> Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting

from the WCF RIA Services toolkit. It contains the type `SoapXmlEndpointFactory`.

The default location is ... `%Program Files%\Microsoft SDKs\RIA Services\v1.0\Toolkit\Libraries\Server`

Comment: Thank you! It took me a while to see the difference between the two DLLs.

Answer (score 1):

The `SoapXmlEndpointFactory` class is part of the

> Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting

assembly, which is included in the Silverlight Toolkit.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicemodel.domainservices.hosting.soapxmlendpointfactory%28VS.91%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
<sectionGroup name="system.serviceModel">
  <section name="domainServices" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServicesSection, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
```

Declare this in the ConfigSections. It's important to include the sectionGroup correctly